# Debugging a strange scenario in SQL Server 2016 with regards to stored procedure execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, query-performance

In our organization, we have SQL Server VM on Azure with always on availability group with 2 nodes.

**Scenario:**

1. We have one procedure called "SP_xyz" and it contains one select query with few inner joins to get list of credential holders. After some load, this stored procedure (SP) started running slow and hence we have optimized this and put that SP back in production and it was running fine for some time.
2. After couple of months as load increased, again there is slowness issue in this SP and again we analysed this SP and optimized. Now the mystery comes, Just to cross verify the new optimized SP, we created the same SP with _test in production. The new SP is "SP_xyz_Test".
3. When we ran this new _Test SP in prod with same set of parameters for which old SP (SP_xyz) was running slow, the new optimized SP gave results in milliseconds against few seconds of older SP.
4. To our surprise, the next movement when we ran the old SP, it also started giving results in milliseconds. This really scared us as where all this kind of issue would be there in production, as we have around 300+ SQL stored procedures.

We did analyse few things that we could think of to find the root cause:

1. Index rebuild
2. Stats update

Also as we know the SP execution plan would be specific to SP name. But here how the old SP has become faster is what we are wondering.

But all these things have been scheduled and were running in production and old SP started running slow. But the movement the new _test SP ran, it has become very fast.

Have we missed anything here, and has anybody has faced this issue before?

Comment: This is not what I am asking for actually. This is very basic things that happens for sprocs in sql server. My question is without changing anything how a Sp can start performing faster just by running the optimized sp with different name on the same db server.

Comment: I think Parameter sniffing might be an issue here

Comment: @TT -- Sorry if the title does not summerize. I put the title as I could think of . I will try to modify

Comment: Its happening for different set of parameters...

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60180/52607

Answer (score 3):

I think with the details you provided ,it is not clear ..But since you are using sqlserver 2016.. you can use querystore to track a statement or stored procedure execution over time

A query might have different plans over time and one plan may perform better and one may not ..So when you enable query store, you can see all the plan changes over time in the regressed query section,which can help you analyze why one plan is taking more time than the another..At least its a starting point..

below is a query with different plan(dots represent new plans over time) and place where the plotted on the graph indicates time taken

[image]

Comment: This will help to identify the query plans before and after. But in production we have not enabled the query store to capture the plans. So we dont have the stats with us to verify. But before that what made it to change the query plan is my basic question?

Comment: Query plan change can occur due to many reasons..stats out of date/stats recompile,table changes..recompile hints..are few  i know

Comment: exactly but all these things were happening regularly on the server and this SP was running slow. It has become fast the movement we tested the optimized sp with different name (_test).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you got the answer for this.

I guess it is typical case of execution plans get outdated due to the dynamic nature of your procedure.

Try `recompile` option.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_xyz
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
 .......
END
GO
```

Comment: we tried this but no luck..anyways even if it works how do we make sure in production how many SPs needs to be recompiled periodically..also this won't be feasible to do.as we can't use this option in all slow running SPs as the whole idea of stored procedure in terms of performance is compromised.